# Why do I need __init__.py at every level?

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

Given that I have the following directory structure with `.` being the current working directory

```
.
\---foo
    \---bar
        \---__init__.py
        \---baz.py
```

When I run `python -c "import foo.bar.baz"` I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1
ImportError: No module named foo.bar.baz
```

If I `echo "" > foo/__init__.py`, the above command works.

Am I doing something wrong or do I  misunderstand the point of `__init__.py`?  I thought it was to stop modules existing where they shouldn't, e.g. a directory named `string`, but if you replace `foo` with `string` in my example, I'm seemingly forced to create the module that should never be used, just so I can reference a file deeper in the hierarchy.

**Update**

I'm working with a build system that's generating the `__init__.py`'s for me and is enforcing the directory structure and while I could mess with the hierarchy, I'd prefer to just add the `__init__.py` myself. To change the question slightly, why do I need a python package at every level instead of just at the top? Is it just a rule that you can only import modules from the python path or from a chain of packages off of the python path?

Comment: Indeed you do... You can do `import bar.baz`, that's valid. But `foo` isn't recognised as a package until it has `__init__.py`.

Comment: Yup, `__init__.py` says "you can import me"

Comment: The question is different because I'm not asking how a `__init__.py` creates a module. It's more asking about what makes a module importable. Can you only import a module via a chain of packages off of a directory on the python path or can you import a module via a chain of packages _and directories_?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, this file is required if you want directory to be treated as a module.

> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In the simplest case, `__init__.py` can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the `__all__` variable, described later.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

In a `__init__.py` file you have great possibility to document module, to get rid of the nested imports for a user/developer by providing the most useful objects(classes/functions) at the first level... ...actually to be as simple in use as possible.

**Edit after question update**

The default importer/finder (examine the `sys.meta_path`) is:

1. [BuiltinImporter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.machinery.BuiltinImporter) - searches for/load a built-in module
2. [FrozenImporter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.machinery.FrozenImporter) - searches for/loads frozen module (e.g. *.pyc)
3. [PathFinder](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.machinery.PathFinder) - the one you are interested in, allow to search for/loads a module based on the file system

The third is the `__init__.py` thing (actually the `FrozenImporter` as well).

The`PathFinder` searches for a module in the paths from `sys.path` (and in `__path__` defined in a package). The module could be either a standalone python file (if it is in the root of the search path) or a directory with `__init__.py`.

Referring to your example:

```
foo/
  bar/
    __init__.py
    baz.py
```

- If you create `__init__.py` in `foo/`, `foo.bar.baz` will be available (as you said).
- If you add `foo/` to `sys.path` or pass it through `PYTHONPATH=foo/`, `bar.baz` will be available (note without parent module `foo`).
- If you write your own [finder](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.abc.MetaPathFinder) (and [loader](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-loader)) you can load for example any file you want despite where it is. That gives you great power. For example take a look on [`stack-overflow-import`](https://github.com/drathier/stack-overflow-import), exposes code based on SO's search results.